# Fullcalendar returning invalid date in sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I am trying to use the plugin FullCalendar in my current project. I am using ajax to load the events, followed by a render command. My biggest problem now is the sidebar. If I put static start and end dates, I always have an "invalid" end date even though they are the same? Here is the code:

```
  //get calendar events
  $.post('/data/api/get-class-events/', {class_id: $('#classId').val()}, function (data) {
      $.each(data, function(index, element) {
          var items = data[index]['fields'];
          var calendarObject = {
                bg: 'blue',
                description: items['details'],
                end: '2017-02-02T05:15:00',
                start: '2017-02-02T05:15:00',
                title: items['title']
            }
            calendarEvents.push(calendarObject)

      });
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', calendarEvents );
  }, 'json');
```

This still gives me an invalid end date. I really don't understand how it can be invalid when it works for the start date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but if you put the end date end to a later date will it work, it may throw up the same error if the end date is before the start date.

Comment: It didn't work when start and end were the same but it worked as soon as I made the end time 1 minute after. I'll mark this as the answer for future reference.